# Allow entering negative sign first for Android EditText of number type

Tags: android, android-edittext, virtual-keyboard, android-inputtype

I have multiple EditText with

```
android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

and that works for the most part except when trying to enter negative numbers, I have to enter at least one numeric digit (0~9) first then move cursor to the front to enter the negative sign. I understand that "-" is not a valid "signed decimal number", but forcing the user to move cursor for every field with negative number is counter productive.

Is there a way to make `numberSigned` allow entering negative sign first, or do I have to implement a custom `InputFilter` to duplicate most of `"numberSigned|numberDecimal"` behavior except to allow entering negative sign first?

I have tested this with both Android 8.1 emulator and Android 9 Motorola e6, in case this matters.

**EDIT**

The title incorrectly assumes "numberSigned" does not allow entering negative sign first by default. It is instead a bug I introduced when I created an InputFilter for these EditText – I accidentally rejected "-" as a valid entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy solution would be to use the `digits` keyword.

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-,."
/>
```

Harder solution would be to implement an `InputFilter` or a `TextWatcher`, and make them "override" the `inputType` behaviour when character is "-" to assess no further work is needed.

Comment: I have an InputFilter, but didn't realize I accidentally filtered out "-" in it... Thank you!